# Manage nesting in LESS

Tags: css, nested, less

I want to get something like

```
.classA, .classB, .classC, .classD, .classE {
  color: white;
}

.classA .classI, .classB .classI, classC .classI {
  background: red;
}
```

is this possible with something like

```
.classA, .classB, .classC {
  color: white;
  .classI {
    background: red;  
  }
}
```

class D and E shouldn't geht the class I.

hopefully you know, what I mean

Comment: What do you mean by shouldn't get the class? You mean `.classC .classI` and `.classD .classI` selectors should not be produced in output?

Comment: `.classA` - `.classD` should just be a white text, no red background, so `classA` to 'classC` should have a syntax like `.class A .class` and classD just `.classD`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case you shouldn't use `.classD` and `.classE` at the top level because the nested selector doesn't apply to all of them.

You should just use `.classA, .classB, .classC` and then use `:extend` for the other two.

```
.classA, .classB, .classC {
  color: white;
  .classI {
    background: red;  
  }
}
.classD, .classE {
  &:extend(.classA);
}
```

When compiled it would result in the following CSS:

```
.classA, .classB, .classC, .classD, .classE {
  color: white;
}
.classA .classI, .classB .classI, .classC .classI {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes like that:

```
.classA {
  color: white;
  &.classI {
    background: red;  
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, how does this answer the question?